# strange file locks on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7-x64

I have a strange problem with my windows 7 (64 bit professional). My compiler output binaries (.exe) files are locked after running. They are locked for about 5 minutes. So I can't compile a new version, I have to wait until it is unlocked. The programm or the debugger are not running (according to the task manager), I used the unlocker (http://www.emptyloop.com/unlocker/) but only got an "access denied". In the Windows Expolorer I can't delete the file, "access denied". I suspected the anti virus programm (Avira Antivir), so I deactivated the realtime scan and added an exception for the output file. No changes.

This happens with different development environments and different compilers:

- Qt Creator with MinGW (Qt5)
- Qt Creator with MSVC 10 (Qt5)
- Sharp Develop with C# .NET 4.5

I hope anyone has an idea why my windows behaves that strange or, even better, how to solve it.

Comment: Try the search feature of  [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) to see what program has the file opened. You can even close the file handle without killing the process!

Comment: Thanks for the Process Explorer. But it found nothing (searched while the file was locked). I also (temporarily) removed my antivirus software, no change. The file is still locked for several minutes. I tried to build on an other physical drive (SSD and HDD both with NTFS), same lock.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found the answer. After I started the "Application Experience Service", the problem was gone.